# module Ecto.Query is not loaded and could not be found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to import Ecto.Query through elixir shell following an example exercice from Programming Phoenix's book and it gives me this error

```
iex> import Ecto.Query

** (CompileError) iex:3: module Ecto.Query is not loaded and could not be found
```

Does anybody know if this been deprecated or is other way to import it?

Comment: Did you start iex with `iex -S mix` from within a project that includes `ecto` as dependency?

Comment: ahh well, damn, I totally forgot those parameters, I am mixing plain Elixir exercices with Phoenix and in this case I just ran iex, without -S mix parameters, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`iex` does not load the project or its dependencies by default, even if you start it from a directory inside the project. In order to load your project and its dependencies in `iex`, you need to do `iex -S mix`, which will execute the `mix` script after starting `iex`, which loads the appropriate .beam files into the REPL.